# Error 1016 when executing Argo Tunnel from Node child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, localhost, cloudflare

**Cloudflare Argo Tunnel from Node child_process**

I have an electron app from which I would like to spawn a child process that executes

```
cloudflared tunnel --url localhost:3000
```

inside a certain directory. Executing this from cmd inside that directory instantiates the argo tunnel as expected, and the url works while the process is running. This is how I am executing the command from the electron app:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

let tunnel = spawn('cloudflared', ['tunnel', '--url', 'localhost:4000'], {
  stdio: 'inherit', // Will use process .stdout, .stdin, .stderr
  cwd: 'c://cloudflare'
})
```

I can see the normal console output from cloudflare indicating that the tunnel has been established and my server is responding at some-random-name.trycloudflare.com. However, when the process is started from within the electron app, I get Error 1016 displayed on a cloudflare error page.

Does anyone have experience with Argo Tunnel and child_process?

Comment: I dont have any experience with cloudflare, but the error code means, that cloudflare does not find your origin PC (so some kind of IP mismatch). First of all in your cmd example you have `localhost:3000` and in your electron example you have  `localhost:4000`, so that might be something you overlooked? Other than that: are you running your Electron app on  a local server? This might be another problem source.

Comment: I have Electron Fiddle installed, as well as `cloudflared` cli, and was able to spawn a child_process that executes "cloudflared tunnel --url localhost:3000" where the Argo Tunnel works as expected. [No problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57735307/712765)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get your setup to work on my Mac without issue, so you need to look further into the details of your setup. Here is what I did:

1. Installed [Electron Fiddle v0.9.0](https://github.com/electron/fiddle/releases/tag/v0.9.0) from GitHub
2. Installed `cloudflared` version 2019.8.4 via `homebrew` with

   ```
   brew install cloudflare/cloudflare/cloudflared
   ```
3. From the command line (Terminal window), ran

   ```
   cloudflared tunnel --url localhost:3000
   ```

   `cloudflared` had some complaints:

   - > Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /usr/local/etc/cloudflared /etc/cloudflared]
   - > cloudflared will not automatically update when run from the shell
   - > unable to connect to the origin error="Get http://localhost:3000: dial tcp [::1]:3000: connect: connection refused"
4. Started a web server on localhost:3000 with

   ```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000
   ```
5. Loaded the page http://localhost:3000 in my browser
6. Again ran

   ```
   cloudflared tunnel --url localhost:3000
   ```

   Same complaints, except this time it was able to connect:

   > Proxying tunnel requests to http://localhost:3000
7. Further output from `cloudflared` indicated it was bringing up 4 tunnels. For each tunnel, it output

   ```
   +-----------------------------------------------------------+
   |  Your free tunnel has started! Visit it:                  |
   |    https://sides-universe-gym-metadata.trycloudflare.com  |
   +-----------------------------------------------------------+
   Route propagating, it may take up to 1 minute for your new route to become functional
   ```

   Note that I did not change or obfuscate the URL, that is exactly what was output, and `cloudflared` output the same URL 4 times, once for each tunnel.
8. I went to https://sides-universe-gym-metadata.trycloudflare.com and verified it displayed the same website I had brought up on localhost:3000.
9. I quit `cloudflared` by typing  `ctrl-c` in the Terminal window where it was running. It took quite some time to shut down, but I waited until it quit.
10. I went to https://sides-universe-gym-metadata.trycloudflare.com and verified it displayed an error. It displayed "Error 1016" and "Origin DNS error".
11. In Electron Fiddle, I selected `Electron v6.0.6` and used the default, pre-installed `main.js`, `index.html`, and `renderer.js`. In `main.js`, I added at the bottom

    ```
    const { spawn } = require('child_process')

    let tunnel = spawn('cloudflared', ['tunnel', '--url', 'localhost:3000'], {
      stdio: 'inherit', // Will use process .stdout, .stdin, .stderr
      cwd: '/Users/user/development'
    })
    ```
12. I clicked "Run" on Electron Fiddle. The "Hello World!" page came up. The Electron Console showed output from `cloudflared`.

    - Again `cloudflared` brought up 4 tunnels, each with the URL https://citysearch-celebs-generator-history.trycloudflare.com
    - `cloudflared` then logged:
    - > cloudflared has been updated to version 2019.8.4
    - > PID of the new process is 81076
    - > Quitting...
    - > Metrics server stopped
    - I have no idea why it "updated" from "2019.8.4" to "2019.8.4". Maybe it has something to do with not having a default configuration, maybe it had something to do with Electron Fiddle running it from a non-standard location. I suspect it is because the command line did not include `--is-autoupdated=true`.
    - Immediately after "Metrics server stopped" `cloudflared` started logging its startup messages, just as before.
    - Again it brought up 4 tunnels, this time with URL https://gifts-jpg-treasury-correct.trycloudflare.com
    - Total time elapsed from start through restart to last stable tunnel up: 14 seconds.
13. I went to https://gifts-jpg-treasury-correct.trycloudflare.com in my local browser and again got the site I was hosting at localhost:3000.
14. I hit "Stop" in Electron. The Electron server stopped, but `cloudflared` kept running. I could still load https://gifts-jpg-treasury-correct.trycloudflare.com/
15. I hit "Run" in Electron. Again `cloudflared` brought up 4 tunnels. This time it did not auto-update or restart. The 4 new tunnels all had the same new URL: https://reject-pride-built-twisted.trycloudflare.com/
16. I went to https://reject-pride-built-twisted.trycloudflare.com/ in my local browser and again got the site I was hosting at localhost:3000. I tried https://gifts-jpg-treasury-correct.trycloudflare.com and it, too, was still working.

So I cannot reproduce your problem. Possible issues are that you may have been looking at the first tunnel that came up but `cloudflared` had updated, closed that tunnel, and started a different one. This worked for me on Mac but it seems you are working on Windows so it could be some Windows-specific issue. It could be that you do not have a server running on `localhost:4000` or that your Electron app cannot access `C://clouflare`.

You need to provide more information, such as the log output of your Electron app running `cloudflared` and details about the server running at `localhost:4000` and any `cloudflared` configuration files you have set up.

Answer (score 1):

**Common cause** 
Cloudflare cannot resolve the origin web server’s IP address.

Common causes for Error 1016 are:

A missing DNS A record that mentions the origin IP address.
A CNAME record in Cloudflare DNS points to an unresolvable external domain.
The origin host names (CNAMEs) in your Cloudflare Load Balancer default, region, and fallback pools are unresolvable. Use a fallback pool configured with an origin IP as a backup in case all other pools are unavailable.
Resolution

**To resolve error 1016:**

**1)** Verify your Cloudflare DNS settings include an A record that points to a valid IP address that resolves via a DNS lookup tool.

**2)** For a CNAME record pointing to a different domain, ensure that the target domain resolves via a DNS lookup tool.

Comment: It is not terribly helpful to copy and paste documentation from another website without comment or elaboration. Also, this does not apply to the OP's problem since he is using `some-random-name.trycloudflare.com` which is fully managed by Cloudflare and does not appear in "your Cloudflare DNS settings".